# Why packages that are not in the required by list of apk info -r cannot be removed in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

My Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.21.4-alpine
RUN apk update && \
    apk del ncurses ncurses-libs ncurses-terminfo-base && \
    apk add ncurses ncurses-libs ncurses-terminfo-base --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main && \
    apk upgrade
```

When I build my image I can see the following output:

```sh
#10 1.022 World updated, but the following packages are not removed due to:
#10 1.023   ncurses-libs: nginx-module-njs
#10 1.023   ncurses-terminfo-base: nginx-module-njs
#10 1.023
#10 1.023 OK: 25 MiB in 42 packages
```

My understanding based on the output is `ncurses-libs` & `ncurses-terminfo-base` cannot be removed because both are required by `nginx-module-njs`.

In order to verify, I started a container based on the built image and ran the following command in the container:

```sh
apk info -r ncurses-libs
```

and this is the output:

```sh
ncurses-libs-6.2_p20210612-r0 is required by:
ncurses-6.3_p20211120-r0
readline-8.1.0-r0
libedit-20210216.3.1-r0
```

My question is if `nginx-module-njs` is dependent on `ncurses-libs` why it is not listed in the output?

Comment: Did you also check for transitive dependencies?

Comment: How can I check the transitive dependencies?

Comment: In the same way as you check other dependencies, but you do it recursively: `apk info -r readline` etc.

Comment: Yes, `libedit` was required by `nginx-module-njs`. It was a transitive dependency. If you want you can create and answer and I'll mark it as correct answer